# Why is my scope property not visible in the view?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, typescript

I use TypeScript to build my Angular application.

Here's my routing:

```
app.config(["$routeProvider", ($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider) => {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/Movie/:imdb', {
            templateUrl: '/Partials/Movie/Details.html',
            controller: 'MovieController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/Rent'
        });
}]);
```

Here is my controller:

```
module MovieApp {
    export interface IMovieControllerScope extends ng.IScope {
        movie: Movie;
    }

    export interface RouteParams extends ng.route.IRouteParamsService {
        imdb: string;
    }

    export class MovieController {
        public static $inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'MovieService'];

        constructor(
            private $scope: IMovieControllerScope,
            private $routeParams: RouteParams,
            private MovieService: MovieService) {

            var imdb = $routeParams.imdb;
            MovieService.GetMovieByImdb(imdb).then(response => {
                this.$scope.movie = response;
            });

        }

    }

    app.controller("MovieController", MovieApp.MovieController);
}
```

And this is my view

```
<div>
    Movie title... {{vm.movie.Title}}
</div>
```

The only thing I see is 'Movie title... '. I just can't figure out how to get this work.

I've tried to remove the `controllerAs` line in the routings and then remove `vm.` in my view, but still with no success.

What am I doing wrong and how to fix this?

EDIT:

This is what TypeScript makes of my controller:

```
var MovieApp;
(function (MovieApp) {
    var MovieController = (function () {
        function MovieController($scope, $routeParams, MovieService) {
            var _this = this;
            this.$scope = $scope;
            this.$routeParams = $routeParams;
            this.MovieService = MovieService;
            var imdb = $routeParams.imdb;
            MovieService.GetMovieByImdb(imdb).then(function (response) {
                _this.$scope.movie = response;
            });
        }
        MovieController.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'MovieService'];
        return MovieController;
    })();
    MovieApp.MovieController = MovieController;

    app.controller("MovieController", MovieApp.MovieController);
})(MovieApp || (MovieApp = {}));
```

Comment: not familiar with Typescript . What does  `this` resolve to inside the callback? When coded in native js `this` would lose context inside callback and would also be `$scope.movie = ...` when no controllerAs or `thisStoredVariable.movie = ...`

Comment: I don't understand your last part 'when no controllerAs or thisStoredVariable.movie = ...'. I have updated my post to show what TypeScript generates

Comment: Does `MovieService` invoke a digest cycle in its callbacks? You might need a `$scope.apply` in your `then` otherwise

Comment: I think deleted answer pointed out the right mistace about `this.$scope.` to  `this.movie`. Question is did you check what is `response` ? If `getmovieByImdb`  does not do any manipulation of data and you are directly chaingin with `then`, you need to get data as `response.data`. Without seeing your service it will be difficult for us to help!!

Comment: @PSL You pointed me in the right direction. The problem was I was using `response.data`. I needed to remove the `.data` part, because I am using Web Api 2 Controllers with MVC.

Comment: Always debug your own code before posting. Will save hell a lot of time. :)

Comment: @PSL ! know and i usually always do, but I guessI was somewhere else with my mind. Could you create an answer so I can mark your suggestions as an answer?